# AWS Boto3 SQS MessageBody vs MessageAttributes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am setting up a SQS queue to ingest a block of config data to be processed by a backend container. My first idea was to `json.dumps` the dictionary with the config info and pass it through the `MessageBody` parameter of `sqsclient.send_message()`. However, after reading through the docs I saw there is also a `MessageAttributes` parameter which seems like I can pass key-value pairs into relatively easily ([Docs for sqsclient.sendmessage()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.send_message))

I am quite unsure of the difference and if there is any benefit to using one over the other. For reference I am ingesting the queue in a python script running on a container in an EC2 instance.

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSMessageAttributes.html of specific note is that you can only have 10 message attributes per message.

Comment: @MarkB So if I understand correctly, the benefit is data type validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So if I understand correctly, the benefit is data type validation?

No.

The benefit is that the metadata is essentially out-of-band: you can attach metadata -- information about the payload -- to the "outside" of an SQS message, without modifying (or even necessarily understanding) what you're going to put "inside" the message (the body).

If the information in question **is part of** the message, it should probably go in the body.  If, on the other hand, it is **about** the message, you may want to attach it as metadata.

For the case you described, go with JSON in the message body.